# Upgraded from Python 3.5 to 3.7, but IPython still uses 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, ipython

I recently installed Python 3.7.2 from the [source tarball](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/), on a computer running Mint 17.3 Rosa. The command `python3` opens the 3.7 interpreter. However, `ipython` still runs with Python 3.5.6. How do I make 3.7 the default for IPython ?

I tried editing the first line of /usr/local/bin/ipython, but then I just get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'` error when I run `ipython`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid editing distributed files such as `/usr/local/bin/ipython`, unless you really have to.

Instead, you should try:

```sh
$ python3.7 -m pip install ipython
$ python3.7 `which ipython3`
```

Comment: That first line gives me `ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`

Comment: And the second one says `File "/usr/local/bin/ipython3", line 6, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'`

Comment: Oh sorry, see edit, I've fixed the first command --- I forgot to add ipython at the end!

Comment: Now I'm getting `pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`, but I'm guessing that's a totally different problem.

Comment: Okay, it looks like you're missing some packages to use pip. Try: ```sudo apt install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev``` and then try ```python3.7 -m pip install ipython``` again.

Comment: I already have the newest version of each of those librairies

Comment: Hm. I'm running our of ideas. Did you install pip with ```sudo apt install python3-pip```? You could also try the above attempts with ```pip3``` instead of ```pip```.